# Mybatis - Pull user defined type from Oracle via stored procedure

Tags: handler, mybatis

I got the error "20:13:20.156 INFO  org.ssc.gss.service.TestServiceTest - org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29478:" although I already defined the result map type handler. It completely ignored my handler

Here's my Oracle code about the tables and the type:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
    ID NUMBER ,
    NAME VARCHAR2(40) unique,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200),
        CONSTRAINT CLIENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX  ENABLE
    )
/

CREATE TABLE DELIVERABLES (
                              ID NUMBER ,
                              NAME varchar2(30),
                              CLIENTID NUMBER,
                              DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200)
)
    /
CREATE TYPE BASEENTITYTYPE IS OBJECT
(
ID NUMBER,
NAME VARCHAR2(30),
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200)
);
/
```

Here's my Oracle definition about the function and the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_base_details(
  i_p_id IN number,
  i_p_type IN VARCHAR2
) return BASEENTITYTYPE
IS
 o_detail BASEENTITYTYPE;
BEGIN
 o_detail :=  BASEENTITYTYPE(i_p_id, null, null);

BEGIN
CASE
  WHEN UPPER(i_p_type) = 'CLIENT'
    THEN
SELECT NAME, DESCRIPTION INTO o_detail.NAME, o_detail.DESCRIPTION FROM CLIENTS where ID = o_detail.id;
END case;
END;

return o_detail;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS
AS
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 for
 SELECT d.name, d.DESCRIPTION, get_base_details(d.clientID,'CLIENT')  client  FROM deliverables d;
DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);
END;
/
```

To populate the data:

```
 INSERT INTO CLIENTS(ID, NAME, description) values (1, 'A','AAA');
 INSERT INTO CLIENTS(ID, NAME, description) values (2, 'B','bbb');
 insert into deliverables values(1,'D1',1, 'CCC');
```

If I ran below in sqlplus command Line:

```
exec TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS()
```

I can get the result as below:

```
NAME | DESCRIPTION | CLIENT(ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D1 | CCC | BASEENTITYTYPE(1, 'A', 'AAA')
```

Here's my java:

BaseEntity:

```
@Data
public class BaseEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

TestEntity:

```
@Data
public class TestEntity {
    private String name;
    private String[] filename;
    private BaseEntity client;
}
```

mapper.java

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
       List<TestEntity> getAll();
}
```

mapper.xml:

```
   <resultMap id="TestEntity" type="org.ssc.gss.entity.TestEntity">
        <result property="client" column="client" typeHandler="org.ssc.gss.utils.OracleBaseEntityHandler" javaType="org.ssc.gss.entity.TestEntity"/>
    </resultMap>
 <select id="getAll"  statementType="CALLABLE"  resultMap="TestEntity" >
        call TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS()
    </select>
```

As I have assigned the typeHandler for the resultmap, column "client", I would expect it went through my defined handler but it didn't - when I did the insert using the parameter handler it did(it's the same hander but different methods)

Any thoughts please?

Comment: It seems that MyBatis does not support Oracle's `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT()` at the moment, unfortunately. CURSORs must be returned as OUT parameters. Here is an [example](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806).

Comment: thanks Ave - good to know it's not supported. I tried use the out parameter now I got a different issue though. I am going to post a new thread to not confuse the others when they read this one.